# Why not concatenate two frequently used words into a new one?

Tags: prepositions, determiners, expressions

I will probably get a lot of flak about this, but why not combine the often used together words "with the" into "withe" which is pronounced *similarly*, and it much shorter and easier to write?

I am sure there are other candidates for such concatenations, which are bound to show up especially in the world of Twitter and SMS messages.

PS. English is my 2nd language.

Comment: Well, for a start, "withe" is not pronounced the same as "with the".

Comment: ja72 should love German and all its commonlyconcatenatedwords.

Comment: But we do combine words together: *it's*, *we've*, *didn't*.  We just don't do every possible combination.

Comment: The term *wrt* is *with respect to*, which IMHO is more efficient and prolly better. FWIW, Yilz had a similar proposal: http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/twain.htm.

Comment: How do you propose this is done? There is no authority which tells people to write "withe" or not. You can start using it yourself, and hope other people catch on - that is the only way words enter the language. Dictionaries only include words if they are already widely used.

Comment: *I will probably get a lot of flak about this,* Probably not as much as you deserve. *but why not combine the often used together words "with the" into "withe"* -- Yes, do that if you want and tell us how it goes. Once more than 75% of the native English speaking word accepts it, you will be famous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because suggestions for new words are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

It is not exactly true that *with the* and *withe* are pronounced in the same way (compare /wɪð ði/ and /wɪð/). Also, *withe* is an English word that means "a tough flexible branch of an osier or other willow, used for tying, binding, or basketry."

Both of these facts have probably contributed to preventing *with the* from being shortened into *withe*.

If you are asking why other words are not shortened in a similar way, then there is no answer. English, like any other natural language, is not changed because a group of people meet to decide what to change in the language.

Comment: I pronounce "with" as /wɪθ/, except when it gets voiced due to voicing assimilation.

Answer (score 3):

With and the are used frequently and not always together. So combining them in this way means a reader has to recognize with, the, and withe. It would seem to me that this would make reading much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that concatenating two words into one would require many English speakers to retrain themselves in standard reading.  I have always considered the point for using proper grammar and spelling to make it as easy as possible for the reader or listener to understand what it is you want to say.

Turning "with the" into "withe" and other similar situations would interrupt normal reading flow.

For non-native speakers, in addition to learning the differences between "there" "they're" and "their" or "bear" (the animal) and "bear" (to carry a burden,) learning another set of shortened/combined words would make English more difficult to learn fluently.

Comment: I'm not sure one extra word is going to impact severely on English learning.  The other few thousand words that do not follow the rules will not help either.

Comment: Agree, but presumably this shortening of words would not be limited to just one word.  Why make things even more complicated?  My main point in the above, though, was that anything non-standard interrupts normal reading flow.  U can red lik this, but iz it as fst?

Comment: See White (in Strunk & White) on the use of *thru/thruway* as opposed to *through/throughway* - I personally can read *throughway* more quickly, I'm bound to say.

Answer (score -1):

"Because".  ;-)

But it's a good idea, though I'd priotitize on a lot of other words, and among them would be eliminating apostrophe from some more often used concatenations.  And there is an easy way to accomplish such changes.  Just start doing it in real communication and hope it catches on, especially widely read groups. If it hits the mainstream, dictionarys will incorporate it.  (Do not try it in english studying, where you'll get points knocked off for unapproved (wrong) usage.)  And look at "Ebonics" as an example. ie babydaddy.  Predominantly black American english speakers creating their own lingo and they cross into common usage.  Language is a living, changing communication.

Comment: ELU is another place where you'll get points knocked off for [recommending] unapproved (wrong) usage. Please check at the Help Center for approved practice.